# Not able to use unarchive module to untar file.tar.gz folder also when used shell module facing error

Tags: linux, macos, shell, ansible, ansible-module

My playbook with shell module

```
 - name: Unarchive  macports from local machine
      shell: |
        tar -xvf MacPorts-2.6.2.tar.gz
        cd MacPorts-2.6.2
        ./configure 
        make
        make install
```

Error
[WARNING]: Consider using the unarchive module rather than running 'tar'.  If you need to use command because unarchive is insufficient you can add 'warn: false' to
this command task or set 'command_warnings=False' in ansible.cfg to get rid of this message.
fatal: [X.X.X.X]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "tar -xvf MacPorts-2.6.2.tar.gz\ncd MacPorts-2.6.2\n./configure\nmake \nmake install\n", "delta": "0:00:00.026259", "end": "2020-06-03 15:54:26.259407", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2, "start": "2020-06-03 15:54:26.233148", "stderr": "tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open 'MacPorts-2.6.2.tar.gz'\n/bin/sh: line 1: cd: MacPorts-2.6.2: No such file or directory\n/bin/sh: line 2: ./configure: No such file or directory\nmake: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.\nmake: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.", "stderr_lines": ["tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open 'MacPorts-2.6.2.tar.gz'", "/bin/sh: line 1: cd: MacPorts-2.6.2: No such file or directory", "/bin/sh: line 2: ./configure: No such file or directory", "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.", "make: *** No rule to make target`install'.  Stop."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

But i have tar.gz file in target machine, when I use unarchive module to untar facing below issue

TASK [Unarchive  macports from local machine] **************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [X.X.X.]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to find handler for \"/Users/pru5/Documents/ansible/MacPorts-2.6.2.tar.gz\". Make sure the required command to extract the file is installed. Command \"/usr/bin/tar\" detected as tar type bsd. GNU tar required. Command \"/usr/bin/unzip\" could not handle archive."}
 can someone help me to untar file in mac??

Answer (score 1):

I installed jnu-tar, but I am not sure if that helped. Unarchive dint work and with no choice went for shell

```
name: extract tar
shell: |
  cd <file_path>
  tar -xvf <file_path/file_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

First point is to use Full paths with Ansible playbooks .
I would recommend to make as two parts , first will be un-taring the file  using Ansible native module `unarchive` , second part will configure and install using `command`  or `shell` module

```
- name: Extract TAR
  unarchive:
    src: /Users/pru5/Documents/ansible/MacPorts-2.6.2.tar.gz
    dest: /tmp/MacPorts
- name: Install software
  command: cd /tmp/MacPorts && ./configure && make && make install
```

Comment: I tried that way but facing the below error.
```
TASK [Extract TAR] **********************************************************************************************************
fatal: [X.X.X.X]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to find handler for \"/Users/pru5/Documents/ansible/MacPorts-2.6.2.tar.gz\". Make sure the required command to extract the file is installed. Command \"/usr/bin/tar\" detected as tar type bsd. GNU tar required. Command \"/usr/bin/unzip\" could not handle archive."}

Comment: It seams you need gnu tar , Since Apple native tar package is BSD tar , So install gnu tar and retry. `brew install gnu-tar`

Comment: I installed gnu-tar in mac and when I run playbook,  facing below error now 
""An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'
fatal: [X.X.X.X]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""} "" @Shan Sunny